# What are the actual values of True and False ?Do they really change as per the language?

Tags: python-3.x

According to my knowledge,I always remembered the boolean true is "0" and false to be "1".
But when coming to python,

if(0):
    print("True")

Output is
None

Can anyone tell me what exactly the values are?

Answer (score 0):

You can run it in console…:

```
In [1]: True == 1
Out[1]: True

In [2]: False == 0
Out[2]: True
```

or

```
In [1]: int(True)
Out[1]: 1

In [2]: int(False)
Out[2]: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In most languages True or False are mapped to 1 and 0 respectively in case they support casting them. Python is one of those languages (others are for example PHP, ruby, etc). Some languages such as Haskell or others, define them as separate values that cannot be casted and therefore you should not rely on the underlying representation.

You can test this by casting `True` or `False` to `int`

```
$ python
> int(True)
1
> int(False)
0
```

Your idea of 0 being true most likely comes from C/C++. C did not have a `boolean` value initially. Therefore people returned integers. Those integers also encode error values. In order to have multiple error values, you would say 0 is "everything fine" (= true), 1 or above are distinct error values. Note that these conventions supported more than two-states (unlike booleans).

Comment: Thank you very much,this was much needed information to me

Comment: @VijayVj If an answer is sufficient for your needs, please remember to mark it as such.